# Reply button not linked to URL

Tags: php, css, wordpress, reply

In my Wordpress theme the reply button shows but i can't click on it there is no URL linked, this is part of the style.css script:

```
}
ol.commentlist li .reply{
margin-top:10px;
font-size:10px;
width:42px;
height:28px;
text-indent:-9000px;
background:url(images/reply.png);
}
```

If i change the script like below the text REPLY is shown and i can click on it, that's how it supposed to be with the button too:

```
}
ol.commentlist li .reply{
margin-top:10px;
font-size:12px;
}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix it, i am a NOOB :-)

Many thanks in advance!

Website:
http://pietkei.nl

Comment: `<ol class="comment list">
    <?php wp_list_comments(array('style' => 'ol')); ?>
</ol>` will generate your reply button automatically or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments read documentation about wordpress commenting.

Comment: Thanks Rameez. As i said i am a noob, is it possible to edit the script so that it will work and activate the reply.png url?

Answer (score 0):

Your "text-indent:-9000px;" is the problem. The anchor tag is assigned to the reply text. Since you are using "text-indent:-9000px;", it makes the reply text disappear from your view, due to the high value of 9000px.

Remove the line "text-indent:-9000px;" or reduce the value to -5px or 10px, in your css code. Then your button will work I guess. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Winnyboy5, when i remove the line "text-indent:-9000px;" or reduce the value the "reply' button and the text of the link (reply) is showing. The text (reply) is working fine and is connected to the url.